# xpath: how to get partial data from within tag

Tags: html, xpath, html-parsing

How do I get the $10.99 without getting the $11.50?

my code gets both and I do not want what's in the strike tag:

```
$price = trim($tmp_xpath->query("//div[@class='ProductPriceRating']/em")->item(0)->nodeValue);
```

here's the html:

```
<div class="ProductPriceRating">
    <em><strike class="RetailPriceValue">$11.50</strike> $10.99</em>
    <span class="Rating Rating5"><img src="images/IcoRating5.gif" alt="" style="" /></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the `text()` of `em` element:

```
//div[@class='ProductPriceRating']/em/text()
```

Here's what you would have for `$price`:

```
$price = trim($tmp_xpath->query("//div[@class='ProductPriceRating']/em/text()")->item(0));
```

Or, as @adamretter noted, better use `normalize-space()` instead of `trim()`:

```
$price = $tmp_xpath->query("normalize-space(//div[@class='ProductPriceRating']/em/text())")->item(0);
```

Comment: Rather than using the `trim()` from your host language. You could use `normalize-space()` in the XPath, this may be more reliable when dealing with varying `text()` nodes. e.g.

`$price = $tmp_xpath >query("//div[@class='ProductPriceRating']/em/normalize-space(text())")->item(0);`